# How to change font size of bitmap characters in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am making a game in PyOpenGL and I am using some text overlapping. How can I change the font size of the fonts included in `OpenGL.GLUT`?

This is what I have now:

```py
def blit_text(x,y,font,text,r,g,b):
    blending = False 
    if glIsEnabled(GL_BLEND):
        blending = True
    glColor3f(r,g,b)
    glWindowPos2f(x,y)
    for ch in text:
        glutBitmapCharacter(font,ctypes.c_int(ord(ch)))
    if not blending:
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)

blit_text(displayCenter[0] - 5,displayCenter[1] - 5,GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,"*",0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you can't.

[`glutBitmapCharacter`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node76.html) uses [`glBitmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBitmap.xml) to raster (and "blit") the bitmap to the framebuffer, in 1:1 pixel ratio.  Thus the bitmap can't be scaled and the position is set by [`glWindowPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glWindowPos.xml) respectively [`glRasterPos`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml).

If you want to draw a text with a different size then you've to choose a different font, s ee [`glutBitmapCharacter`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node76.html).

When you use `glutStrokeCharacter` then the text is drawn by line primitives. THe thickness of the text can be set by [`glLineWidth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLineWidth.xhtml). The position and size of the text can depends on the current model view matrix a nd projection matrix. So the position of the text can be set by [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and the size can be changed by [`glScale`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glScale.xml). The text can even be rotated by [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml).

e.g.:

```py
def blit_text(x,y,font,text,r,g,b):

    glColor3f(r,g,b)
    glLineWidth(5)
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0)
    glScalef(1, 1, 1)
    for ch in text:
        glutStrokeCharacter(font,ctypes.c_int(ord(ch)))

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight, -1, 1)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()

blit_text(10, 10, GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, "**", 0, 1, 0)
```

See also [freeglut - 14. Font Rendering Functions](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#FontRendering) for the use of `glutBitmapString` respectively `glutStrokeString`.

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)